# Inconsistency, when returning index of duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an algorithm to find duplicate values in a list and return their respective indexes, but the script only returns the correct value, when I have 2 equal elements:

```
array = [1,2,0,5,0]
result -> (2) [2,4]
```

Like the example below:

```
array = [0,0,2,7,0];
result -> (6) [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4]
The expected result would be [0,1,4]
```

Current code:

```js
const numbers = [1,2,0,5,0];

const checkATie = avgList => {
    let averages, tie, n_loop, currentAverage;
    
    averages = [... avgList];
    tie = [];
    n_loop = 0;

    for(let n = 0; n <= averages.length; n++) {
        currentAverage = parseInt(averages.shift());
        n_loop++
        for(let avg of averages) {
            if(avg === currentAverage) {
                tie.push(numbers.indexOf(avg),numbers.indexOf(avg,n_loop))
            };
        };

    };

    return tie;
}

console.log(checkATie(numbers));
```

if possible I would like to know some way to make this code more concise and simple

Comment: What is the intent with your push call? `tie.push(numbers.indexOf(avg),numbers.indexOf(avg,n_loop))`? You’re pushing the first index and the index starting from `n_loop` each time it’s found? And why not use `n` instead of `n_loop`? That’s what the loop variable is for.

Comment: And by calling averages.shift you’re changing the length of the array you’re iterating over.

Comment: Yes, I use the n loop to compensate for the values that have already been verified,

Comment: How many duplicate does the array contains? In case of multiple, what will be the output?

Comment: What is your use case? Hard to see how such results would be very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//duplicate entries as an object
checkDuplicateEntries = (array) => {
  const duplicates = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (duplicates.hasOwnProperty(array[i])) {
      duplicates[array[i]].push(i);
    } else if (array.lastIndexOf(array[i]) !== i) {
      duplicates[array[i]] = [i];
    }
  }
   console.log(duplicates);
}

checkDuplicateEntries([1,2,0,5,0]);
// hope this will help
```

Comment: Differs from expected results

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
return [...new Set(tie)]
```

```js
const numbers1 = [1,2,0,5,0];
const numbers2 = [0,0,2,7,0];
 
const checkATie = avgList => {
    let averages, tie, n_loop, currentAverage;
    
    averages = [... avgList];
    tie = [];
    n_loop = 0;

    for(let n = 0; n <= averages.length; n++) {
        currentAverage = parseInt(averages.shift());
        n_loop++
        for(let avg of averages) {
            if(avg === currentAverage) {
                tie.push(avgList.indexOf(avg),avgList.indexOf(avg,n_loop))
            };
        };

    };

    return [...new Set(tie)]
}

console.log(checkATie(numbers1));
console.log(checkATie(numbers2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you.you can use `foreach` function to check each item of `array`

```js
var array = [0,0,2,7,0];

var result = [] ;
array.forEach((item , index)=>{
  if(array.findIndex((el , i )=> item === el && index !== i ) > -1 ){
    result.push(index)
  }
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why index !== i ?

Comment: we don't want to check an alement with itself, so i and index must not be equal

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup object with value and their indexes and then filter all the values which occurred more than once and then merge all indexes and generate a new array.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2],
  result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, v, i) => {
    r[v] = r[v] || [];
    r[v].push(i);
    return r;
  }, {}))
  .filter((indexes) => indexes.length > 1)
  .flatMap(x => x);
console.log(result);
```